# Proper way of calling a method in a subclass if it's referenced as a super class

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

```
class SuperClass () {
  doSuperStuff();
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass () {
  doStuff();
}

SuperClass aClass = new SubClass();
```

In order to call the method `doStuff()` do I need to cast it like `(SubClass)aClass.doStuff();` ?

1. Is that normally the way to do it?
2. Is there a better way?
3. Should I "always" initialize SubClass that way in case I want to put a bunch
   of subclasses of SuperClass into an array or something like that?

**UPDATE:**
After reading everyone's response:

Ok. I'm definitely missing something in my understanding. I thought that having a subclass inherit everything from the superclass and then making one more method inside the subclass is ok. Should I be making an interface then?

Also, I had `SuperClass class = new SubClass();` but renamed it to `SuperClass aClass = new SubClass();`

Comment: If you need to call a `SubClass` method of something with static type `SuperClass`, something has gone wrong in your design.

Comment: Why would you want to reference it as a super class if you want to call the method in subclass, SubClass class = new SubClass(), then class.doStuff()

Comment: @svasa you cannot call a variable `class` it is a reserved word

Comment: I am just quoting the lines in the code posted above.

Comment: Updated after reading everyone's response.

Comment: It's annoying when people down vote your question and say nothing about it. How am I supposed to pose better questions without any feedback?

Comment: @tazboy I actually upvoted your question, because I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all, if you want to invoke a method from the subclass, in the first place you don't have to use a data type of superclass to create the variable. You could simply:

  ```
  MySubClass obj1 = new MySubClass();
  ```

`obj1` will be able to access both methods from its superclass (due to inheritance, except private methods in the superclass) and from itself.

- Secondly, you can't name a variable as `class`.
- Thirdly, if you want to do a casting, it goes like this:

  ```
  MySuperClass obj2 = new MySubClass();
  ((MySubClass)obj2).doStuff();
  ```

Comment: In response to your first feedback, I guess I just wanted to make my scope bigger in case I wanted to change things up later.

Comment: @tazboy If for any valid reason you are doing point no.1, then you can use point no.3 to downcast it to access the subclass' method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code won't actually work, but yes casting is the only way to do this (but don't).  What you need to do is `((SubClass)class).doStuff();`
2. No.  I would recommend not even doing this
3. No.  If you need a `SubClass`, declare it as a `SubClass`.  If you have a collection of objects that all inherit from `SuperClass` the only methods you *should* be calling are those defined on `SuperClass`.  Doing anything else will lead to horrible, spaghetti like unmaintainable code

Comment: The variable might be an array of the superclass, so it is perfectly acceptable to create it as the superclass:  `animal[I] = new Dog()`; then you might later need to use a subclass method like `((Dog)animal[I]).bark();` Of course you should first verify that animal[I] is a Dog.

Comment: This undoubtedly points towards a problem with your design.  See my point 3 above

Answer (score 1):

If `doStuff()` pertains only to the subclass and has no meaning in the superclass then you should be using subclass instances at that point.

If, however `doStuff()` has semantic validity in all subclasses of the superclass, then the superclass should have an abstract method `doStuff()` that is implemented in all subclasses.

Alternatively, if `doStuff()` applies to only some subclasses you could define an interface with that method and have those subclasses implement the interface.

Which approach you use depends on the overall application structure and you haven't really provided enough information for us to guide you further.

Comment: Do have have to implement every method defined in the interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line will probably not compile

```
SuperClass class = new SubClass();
```

However assuming you have SuperClass clazz = new SubClass(); The declaration is done at compile time and so is the invocation of the methods. Therefore you will only see the methods that are declared on the type with which clazz was declared. So yes if you need to invoke a sub class methods you need to perform the appropriate cast on clazz.

Regarding your second question: this is the correct way to do things if you want to take advantage of polymorphic behaviour... which lead us to your third question. Yes this is the way to take advantage of polymorphism by having a bunch of subclasses's behaviours accessed in a uniform way after storing in a collection or an array declared with the base type