# based on dependency inversion principle, How do I access functions that are only in my child class and not in my interface?

Tags: java, dependency-inversion

How to access A and B function that is only in a sword class and is not in Weapon interface.
Because the sword, bow class are child so that they can be more extended than the weapon class.

The parent class 'Weapon' has the abstract function A from its child classes 'Sword' and 'Bow'. However, due to the unique characteristics of 'Sword' and 'Bow', 'Sword' possesses function B, while 'Bow' possesses function C."

The client can access the 'Weapon' class through the 'BattleService' class, which takes it as an argument in function A. However, it cannot access functions B and C, which are exclusive to the 'Sword' and 'Bow' classes respectively, as they are not part of the interface. How can access be granted in such cases based on dependency Inversion?

I want to output functions B and C from BattleService while adhering to the principle of dependency inversion.

```
public interface Weapon {
  void A();
}


public class Sword implements Weapon {
  @Override
  public void A() {
    System.out.println("Sword A");
  }
   public void B() {
      System.out.println("Sword B");
}


public class Bow implements Weapon {
  @Override
  public void A() {
    System.out.println("Bow A");
  }
  public void C() {
    System.out.println("Bow C");
  }
}

public class BattleService {

  private Weapon weapon;

  public BattleService(Weapon weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
  }

  public void A() {
    weapon.A();
  }
}



public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Weapon sword = new Sword();
    Weapon bow = new Bow();

    BattleService battleService = new BattleService(sword);
    battleService.A(); 

    battleService = new BattleService(bow);
    battleService.A(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: When you need a sword to sharpen it then change the parameter type to `Sword`.  Or use a new interface to describe something that can be sharpened. What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: The derived class inherited from the interface (parent class) can be expanded than the parent class. According to the based on  dependency inversion if we are to access the child classes through the interface, I wonder how we approach functions that are only available to the child class, not in the interface?

Comment: You can't, unless you cast the object or use reflection. If you have other requirement to the value of the parameter, you can use a different type of interface which has the `sharpen()` method. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do, what you have tried and what the problems are.

Comment: I have revised my question in accordance with your advice, aligning it with my intentions and what I wish to achieve, most respectfully.

Comment: You can cast your object, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701182/call-a-method-of-subclass-in-java or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140291/proper-way-of-calling-a-method-in-a-subclass-if-its-referenced-as-a-super-class

Comment: The first method I know of is to create an object of the subclass and access it from BattleService. However, dependency inversion is not about depending on a low-level module, but rather about writing code that depends on an abstracted Interface or other high-level modules. If we call functions directly in the BattleService from the low-level module (sword, bow class), doesn't this violate the principle of dependency inversion? In other words, shouldn't we access through the Weapon Interface to adhere to the principle?

Comment: The second method involves creating a separate interface for functions only available in the subclass and registering it. However, this also seems to violate dependency inversion, as it makes the high-level module dependent on the low-level module, doesn't it?